# How do i display ng-repeat nested values

Tags: angularjs

I have the following object.  How can I only display the rows with the nested values?

```
$scope.mainObj = [{
    name: 'a', items : [1,2,3],
    name: 'b', items : [4,5,6],
}]

<table>
 <tr ng-repeat="obj in mainObj">
        <td></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

I want my output to be:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>1</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>4</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: what are the "nested values"?

Comment: It looks like you need to change `$scope.mainObj` to `[{name: 'a', items:[1, 2, 3]}, {name: 'b', items: [4, 5, 6]}]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could repeat `tbody` of `table` which is valid HTML. **Assuming `items` can have entities.**

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tbody ng-repeat="obj in mainObj">
     <tr ng-repeat="item in obj.items">
        <td>{{item }}</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

**Update**

Correct your object structure as well as @csschapker suggested in comment.

```
$scope.mainObj = [{name: 'a', items:[1, 2, 3]}, {name: 'b', items: [4, 5, 6]}]
```

Comment: what if I have some objects without items?

Comment: @KingKongFrog could you brief out what you are saying?

Answer (score 0):

Use code like this:

```
<table>
 <tr ng-repeat="obj in mainObj">
   <td ng-repeat="item in obj.items track by $index">
     {{item}}
   </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

And edit you source object to :

```
$scope.mainObj = [
  {name: 'a', items: [1, 2, 3]},
  {name: 'b', items: [4, 5, 6]}
];
```

Comment: That doesn't give me on each line.

Comment: try add track by $index - I updated code into answer